# Complex website, need to update buttons that share classes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a test for a fairly complex website. In this test I'm supposed to target a particular group of buttons, the problem is that these buttons share the same classes as the buttons I'm supposed to exclude. This has to be done in jQuery and I don't have access to the source code to add new classes.

The one hope I have left is to exclude the jQuery below from applying to certain parent div classes so that the child `<a>` links don't have the below styles applied.

```
$('a.button.secondary').css({"background-color": "#ffffff", "color": "#000000","border-color": "#838E93", "border-width": "2px", "border-style": "solid", "margin": "2px"});

$('a.button.secondary').mouseenter(function() {
$(this).css("border-width", "4px").css("margin", "0");
}).mouseleave(function() {
$(this).css("border-width", "2px").css("margin", "2px");
});
```

Here is the best example of HTML as I can provide. I want the script to  apply to any of the buttons that doesn't have the molecule-301 parent div.

```
<body>
<div class="molecule-301">
<h2>
<a class="button secondary" href="...">don't touch</a>
</h2>
</div>
<div class="everything-else">
<a class="button secondary" href="...">change me</a>
</div>
</body>
```

It was suggested below to try something like this...

```
$('a.button.secondary').mouseenter(function() {
var test = false;
if ($(this).parents().hasClass('.molecule-301')) test = true;
if (test) $(this).css("border-width", "4px").css("margin", "0");
}).mouseleave(function() {
var test = false;
if ($(this).parents().hasClass('.molecule-301')) test = true;
if (test) $(this).css("border-width", "2px").css("margin", "2px");
});
```

So far though I haven't been able to get this last bit to work quite  right.

Comment: Post your relevant ("[mcve]") HTML, show which elements to include and which to exclude, so that we have a chance of posting a useful answer without having to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest, given the HTML in the question, using a simple selector followed by the `filter()` method:

```
// select all <a> elements with the classes of 'button'
// and 'secondary'; then use filter() to retain only
// those elements you wish to keep:
$('a.button.secondary').filter(function() {
  // the filter() method retains only those elements for
  // which the assessment returns true (or truthy):

  // here we find the closest ancestor element of the
  // current element in the collection that matches the
  // given selector; if the length of that collection
  // is equal to 0, (there are no ancestors matching the
  // selector) we retain that element:
  return $(this).closest('.molecule-301').length === 0;

// and apply the following method to those retained
// elements:
}).css({
  "background-color": "#ffffff",
  "color": "#000000",
  "border-color": "#838E93",
  "border-width": "2px",
  "border-style": "solid",
  "margin": "2px"
});
```

```js
$('.button.secondary').filter(function() {
  return $(this).closest('.molecule-301').length === 0;
}).css({
  "background-color": "#ffffff",
  "color": "#000000",
  "border-color": "#838E93",
  "border-width": "2px",
  "border-style": "solid",
  "margin": "2px"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="molecule-301">
  <h2>
<a class="button secondary" href="...">don't touch</a>
</h2>
</div>
<div class="everything-else">
  <a class="button secondary" href="...">change me</a>
</div>
```

Or, in plain JavaScript – albeit in ES6/ECMAScript 2015 JavaScript – you could use the following:

```
// converting the collection of elements from the collection
// returned by document.querySelectorAll() into an
// Array, using Array.from(); which allows us to use Array
// methods:
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a.button.secondary'))

  // here we use Array.prototype.filter() to retain only those
  // elements for which the assessment within the anonymous
  // function returns true/truthy values:
  .filter(function(el) {
    // 'el' is a reference to the current element of the
    // Array over which we're iterating (the name is user
    // defined).

    // here we retain only those elements that have no
    // ancestor Node matching the supplied selector:
    return !el.closest('.molecule-301');

  // we iterate over the retained elements:
  }).forEach(function(el) {

    // and use the Element.classList API to add
    // a new class-name to the current list of
    // class-names that the Element has (here we
    // add the 'buttonStyle' class-name).
    // This is somewhat easier than updating 
    // multiple CSS properties programatically:
    el.classList.add('buttonStyle');
  });
```

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a.button.secondary'))
  .filter(function(el) {
    return !el.closest('.molecule-301');
  }).forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.add('buttonStyle');
  });
```

```css
.buttonStyle {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-color: #/838E93;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="molecule-301">
  <h2>
<a class="button secondary" href="...">don't touch</a>
</h2>
</div>
<div class="everything-else">
  <a class="button secondary" href="...">change me</a>
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Element.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- jQuery:

  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Thank you very much; I'm glad to have been of use! :)

Comment: Yes this is a fantastic explanation! ++1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps probe the adjacent/parent elements to see if they indicate the `mouseenter` function was triggered by one of the desired elements?  Something like:

```
$('a.button.secondary').mouseenter(function() {
    var test = false;
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('sumclass')) test = true;
    if ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('nutherclass')) test = true;
    if (test) $(this).css("border-width", "4px").css("margin", "0");
}).mouseleave(function() {
    var test = false;
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('sumclass')) test = true;
    if ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('nutherclass')) test = true;
    if (test) $(this).css("border-width", "2px").css("margin", "2px");
});
```

The above code would only allow the css to be added/removed if one of the tests is true.

Comment: That's great, I wasn't able to put the html in my question, but I'm trying to find exclude the styles from being applied to buttons with a parent container with the class "molecule-301".

'<div class="molecule-301">
<h2>
<a class="button secondary" href="whatever">
</h2>
</div>